# What song is playing during the first encounter with Granzeboma?

Tags: music, gurren-lagann

During *Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann: Lagann-hen* (the second movie), the protagonists encounter Granzeboma at about 01:32:30 into the movie, and a battle begins. (A clip of the scene can be found [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/94509321@N06/8602139976/in/photostream); the music begins about 10 seconds in.)

[image: First encounter with Granzeboma]

I've listened to as many of the songs in the OST as I can find, and none match this noble, battle-laden theme. What music is it that plays during this scene? Is it even available?

Comment: I'm tempted to remove both [identification-request] and [music] tags so that [gurren-lagann] appends to the title for better SEO. I'm not sure how common this question is though.

Comment: This isn't an anime identification request; it's a request for the name of a song that plays during an anime. It has a single, unambiguous answer. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Cattua sorry for the confusion since the close reason hasn't been updated at the time this was closed, but [music ID has been declared off-topic since the beginning of 2022](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/so-its-about-time-we-finally-deprecated-music-id-request-questions). Hopefully it's now clear since the close reason has been updated a few hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is from the second OST, track 6, titled **BafBaf! そんなに燃えるのが…好きかい** (*"BafBaf! Sonna ni Moeru no ga...Suki Kai?"*, *"BafBaf! Being Fired Up Like This... Don't You Like It?"*).

The scene in the question starts playing from around 02:28 into the track.

The song was also featured in *Gurren Lagann Parallel Works* [music video #2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Gurren_Lagann_episodes#Gurren_Lagann_Parallel_Works).